# Время жизни для конкретной сессии

Tags: php, сессия, php7

Приветствую!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно задать свое время жизни для конкретной сессии?

```
$_SESSION['log'];//Авторизация
$_SESSION['cart'];//корзина
```

У меня создается сессия на авторизацию пользователя и на добавление товара в корзину. Для авторизационной сессии надо задать свое время жизни, а для корзиной сессии этого делать не нудно.

Возможно ли такое реализовать и как, если можно?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути никак не задать. 
Для начало необходимо понимать, что такое [сессия](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.session.php) и для чего она предназначена.

> Каждому посетителю сайта присваивается уникальный идентификатор, называемый идентификатором сессии (session id). Он хранится либо в cookie на стороне пользователя, либо передается через URL.

То есть сессия должна создаваться одна для сеанса.

Само время жизни общей сессии можно установить в `php.ini`  `session.gc_maxlifetime`

В Вашем же случае, правильным вариантом, скорее будет устанавливать данные в [cookie](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php).

И работать с данными из cookie через [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

Comment: То есть авторизацию лучше выполнить через $_COOKIE? Что-то меняется, если не на сессии это сделать? По-моему, нет)

Comment: @Дима как я понял у Вас одна авторизация + корзина. Можно авторизацию оставить на session, а корзину переделать на cookie

Comment: А, если, наоборот, тоже можно?

Comment: так делать не стоит, с точки зрения безопасности :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо!:) У Вас я считаю более правильный и развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Дима - спасибо ) Вы просто можете в куки добавить информацию по корзине `setcookie("cart", $data, time()+(3600*24));` и не привязываться к сессии. Пользователь завтра зашёл на сайт и Вы просто смотрите его `$_COOKIE["cart"]`

Comment: Но завтра этого товара уже нет в магазине. Опасно так делать) Не для этого куки.

Comment: @vp_arth да,  по хорошему редис бы поставить. А так - это валидировать наличие при покупке ещё надо

Comment: И в оферте придётся написать, что наличие товара в корзине не гарантирует ни наличие товара, ни цены на этот товар...

Comment: @vp_arth кстати, Amway так работало одно время. Делаешь заказ, заходишь на след день а такого товара нет. Но это пол беды, они ещё брали и штрафомали тех, кто не купил/оплатил заказ (а его просто могло и не быть).

Answer (score 4):

Конкретно для $_SESSION вы не сможете указать время жизни. Лучше сделать так, при заполнении $_SESSION['log'] заполнять $_SESSION['log_start'] текущем временем. А потом проверять, не прошло ли слишком много времени.

```
$_SESSION['log_start'] = time();
...
if (time() - $_SESSION['log_start'] > $log_expr_time) {
    сессия протухла
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант был у меня на последнем месте, надеялся, что можно реализовать, как в вопросе, ну ладно, сделаю так:)

Comment: время жизни можно указывать для memcache или Redis или чего-то похожего.